# Regarding splat blur and slice technique in computer vision

Tags: computer-vision

I am new to computer vision and struggling to understand the concept of splat,blur and slice technique for accelerating the gaussian filtering technique. I have been following this dissertation  http://books.google.com/books?id=ihe0nfm97eIC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false.

However, I am a very beginner. So can anyone point me to some basics that could help me understand this technique?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to start from the very basics, there are many good introductory texts on image processing. Personally I liked the Gonzalez-Wintz a lot, but it may be hard to find these days. The [Petrou](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047074586X) one gets good reviews.